# Google Play user install issues

Tags: android, google-play

I have of recently been getting a lot of one star reviews for my Rhonna Designs app on Google Play. Has anyone else dealt with user install errors? If so what can I do to fix it? I hope it is something that I am doing and that the Google infrastructure isn't as bad as it seems.

Here are a few of the one stars I'm getting:

> How on earth can it "not install in the place attempted" ??? Someone please help me install it :( I wasted my money :(
>
> I purchased it and couldn't install it by the error called 961 I just don't get it what a waste of money
>
> I paid for this app and was very excited, but it won't install and just says "error 918". Such a waste of money.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.niftybytes.rhonna_android"
          android:versionCode="37"
          android:versionName="1.4 DEV"
          android:installLocation="auto">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />

    <supports-screens
            android:anyDensity="true"
            android:smallScreens="true"
            android:normalScreens="true"
            android:largeScreens="true"
            android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:largeHeap="true">

        <receiver android:name = "com.amazon.inapp.purchasing.ResponseReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name = "com.amazon.inapp.purchasing.NOTIFY"
                        android:permission = "com.amazon.inapp.purchasing.Permission.NOTIFY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".StartScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SliderActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"/>
        <activity android:name=".FontActivity"
                  android:configChanges="orientation"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name=".DesignActivity"
                  android:configChanges="orientation"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name=".CanvasOptionsActivity"
                  android:configChanges="orientation"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.crashlytics.ApiKey" android:value="xxx"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Please add the manifest file.

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk I added the manifest, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Comments "not install in the place attempted" and "[error 961](https://community.verizonwireless.com/thread/815686)" are pointing to problems with insufficient memory. Internal memory, I guess.
2. Your app is a pretty big one - 44 MB. Make it as small as possible, for example you can [compress](https://tinypng.com/) PNGs. If you can't compress it more, make a really "thin client" and download content. Make an "installer" in couple of MB which will contain everything that's hard to skip (code, layouts etc.) and download the rest of the content to SD card (images etc.) on the first launch from your service at www.some.url.com/content/1142avrh34h34. Show appropriate progress bar to the user.
3. Take a look at the apk installation [process](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/43517/installing-to-sdcard-by-default). First, apk is downloaded to `/data/local`, in the **internal storage**. You can't change that. So, if user is short of internal memory and he downloads and unpacks your 44 MB apk - bad things will happen. This is what causes your problems.
4. Change `android:installLocation="auto"` to `android:installLocation="preferExternal"`. At least an apk after the downloading will be stored on the SD card, saving some space of the internal storage. Usually available memory of the external memory is much greater than internal. From [App Install Location](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html):

   > If you declare `"preferExternal"`, you request that your application be
   >   installed on the external storage, but the system does not guarantee
   >   that your application will be installed on the external storage. If
   >   the external storage is full, the system will install it on the
   >   internal storage. The user can also move your application between the
   >   two locations.
   >
   > If you declare `"auto"`, you indicate that your application may be installed on the external storage, but you don't have a preference of install location. **The system will decide where to install your application based on several factors.** The user can also move your application between the two locations.

Comment: The tinypng site help me save 20MBs thanks for that link. I am currently thinking of how to download after the app installs. I read something that Android has expansion packs (not sure on the name) for when an app goes over a certain size it can add assets to these packs. Would that work?

Comment: @BryanWilliams Great, 20 MB is a good start. Yes, they're called [APK Expansion Files](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you fix error 961: 
----->Clearing the cache and data normally

1) To do this, go into your phone’s settings, then Applications (or Apps or Application Manager), swipe to the left to ”All” and scroll down until you find Google Play, tap on it.

2) In the app information page, tap on the button to empty the cache.

3) If this doesn’t solve the problem, try to delete the data from the Play Store which is found on the same page (Settings > Manage applications > Google Play > Delete data). This will most probably work, since it had worked in my case when I suffered with the problem in my android.

If the problem still persists, try this method:
1) Power off your phone.
2) Hold volume up/down & power simultaneously until you see the Boot Mode Selection Menu
3) Use volume down to navigate to ‘Recovery’, use volume up to select. You should see screen with triangle and exclamation point next to an Android.
4) Press volume up/down simultaneously to go into system recovery.
5) Use volume rocker to navigate to ‘wipe cache’ and use power button to select
6) Once finished, use volume rocker to navigate to ‘reboot system now’ and use power button to select.

Source: http://appslova.com/android-fix-unknown-install-error-961/